# What exactly are the Serial Ports listed and why don't they have a "normal" numbering scheme?

Tags: command-line, usb, serial-number

In Mac one can list their serial ports using

```
ls /dev/tty.*
```

As per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815211/mac-command-line-list-available-serial-ports

But something that baffles me when I do this is that I see output for serial ports that are specific to the devices I own:

```
sidharthghoshal@Sidharths-MBP webrtc-demo % ls /dev/tty.*

/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port    /dev/tty.Sidsworkheadphone-SPPDev    /dev/tty.usbmodem14301         /dev/tty.void_sound-SPPDev
```

Now I would "expect" that something like the USB device I connected `/dev/tty.usbmodem14301` would just have a regular old port number like `tty01` or `tty02`

but when I run

```
    ls /dev/tty*
```

I see what appears to be EVERY POSSIBLE serial port: and it's no longer obvious to me how to correspond a name like `/dev/tty.usbmodem14301` to its "real" serial port number (it's possible that isn't even a well defined question and if it isn't I would like to know why, as I would like to write some code that says effectively “read data from whatever the hell is on USB port #3”).

```
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port    /dev/ttyq3              /dev/ttyra              /dev/ttyse              /dev/ttyu5              /dev/ttyvc
/dev/tty.Sidsworkheadphone-SPPDev   /dev/ttyq4              /dev/ttyrb              /dev/ttysf              /dev/ttyu6              /dev/ttyvd
/dev/tty.usbmodem14301          /dev/ttyq5              /dev/ttyrc              /dev/ttyt0              /dev/ttyu7              /dev/ttyve
/dev/tty.void_sound-SPPDev      /dev/ttyq6              /dev/ttyrd              /dev/ttyt1              /dev/ttyu8              /dev/ttyvf
/dev/ttyp0              /dev/ttyq7              /dev/ttyre              /dev/ttyt2              /dev/ttyu9              /dev/ttyw0
/dev/ttyp1              /dev/ttyq8              /dev/ttyrf              /dev/ttyt3              /dev/ttyua              /dev/ttyw1
/dev/ttyp2              /dev/ttyq9              /dev/ttys0              /dev/ttyt4              /dev/ttyub              /dev/ttyw2
/dev/ttyp3              /dev/ttyqa              /dev/ttys000                /dev/ttyt5              /dev/ttyuc              /dev/ttyw3
/dev/ttyp4              /dev/ttyqb              /dev/ttys001                /dev/ttyt6              /dev/ttyud              /dev/ttyw4
/dev/ttyp5              /dev/ttyqc              /dev/ttys002                /dev/ttyt7              /dev/ttyue              /dev/ttyw5
/dev/ttyp6              /dev/ttyqd              /dev/ttys1              /dev/ttyt8              /dev/ttyuf              /dev/ttyw6
/dev/ttyp7              /dev/ttyqe              /dev/ttys2              /dev/ttyt9              /dev/ttyv0              /dev/ttyw7
/dev/ttyp8              /dev/ttyqf              /dev/ttys3              /dev/ttyta              /dev/ttyv1              /dev/ttyw8
/dev/ttyp9              /dev/ttyr0              /dev/ttys4              /dev/ttytb              /dev/ttyv2              /dev/ttyw9
/dev/ttypa              /dev/ttyr1              /dev/ttys5              /dev/ttytc              /dev/ttyv3              /dev/ttywa
/dev/ttypb              /dev/ttyr2              /dev/ttys6              /dev/ttytd              /dev/ttyv4              /dev/ttywb
/dev/ttypc              /dev/ttyr3              /dev/ttys7              /dev/ttyte              /dev/ttyv5              /dev/ttywc
/dev/ttypd              /dev/ttyr4              /dev/ttys8              /dev/ttytf              /dev/ttyv6              /dev/ttywd
/dev/ttype              /dev/ttyr5              /dev/ttys9              /dev/ttyu0              /dev/ttyv7              /dev/ttywe
/dev/ttypf              /dev/ttyr6              /dev/ttysa              /dev/ttyu1              /dev/ttyv8              /dev/ttywf
/dev/ttyq0              /dev/ttyr7              /dev/ttysb              /dev/ttyu2              /dev/ttyv9
/dev/ttyq1              /dev/ttyr8              /dev/ttysc              /dev/ttyu3              /dev/ttyva
```

Comment: How do you know which USB port is #3? Also, not every USB device acts as a TTY, not every TTY is a USB device. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am attempting to send and receive serial communication from the device represented by `dev/tty.usbmodem14301` and I can use that name to communicate BUT I find it odd there’s no way to communicate with “device on the left laptop port #1” and that I have to actually reference this name I saw listed. I would expect, that there’s another way to do this that’s more “standardized” if you will. I don’t even know how that “14301” got added to the name for example, and if that might change in the future. But something like “USB port #2” would never change on me.

Comment: What happens if you connect an USB hub to port #1, and several devices to that hub? Also, as said, a TTY implies a certain communication standard (which works fine for a modem for instance), USB keyboards or USB drives usually can't be accessed as a TTY.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that these names are merely a "nice name for the user", and not the "actual" reference for the device as used by the operating system itself.

Actually you can create any name you would like to use for your serial ports - as long as they reference the correct device. It is however not referenced by a simple "port number" (as you would expect on for example earlier versions of Windows) - but rather they are referenced by a device type, major device number and minor device number - in the Unix tradition.

If you look at for example your Bluetooth device, you can find the numbers by running a command like this in the Terminal:

```
stat  -f "Name: %N%n%tType: %HT%n%tMajor: %Hr%n%tMinor: %Lr%n%n" /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
```

This will list the type of device (which is always "character" for serial ports) and the major and minor device numbers.

You can create a new "name" for your device by way of the `mknod` command. Choose a name and place in the file system, and make sure you choose the right device type and major and minor numbers, and you have a new way of accessing your device.

So that explains how the system gets from this seemingly "random" name to device numbers that are used internally. However knowing that there is an internal counter of "USB serial port #1" and "USB serial port #2" etc. doesn't really help you much in programmatically finding the right device when you have multiple connected.

If you're used to the Linux operating system, you might know that they use a program called `udevd` to (amongst other things) create a common way of mapping connected devices to device files. With it you might create rules for specifying your names for specific devices, so that no matter when or in which port it is connected, you can always refer to it by a specific name. However, macOS does not use such a `udevd` program.

As for the names of the devices themselves (the default names) - they are actually chosen by the driver for each type of device. That is - there's no common naming scheme that applies to all types of devices.

In particular for your USB serial device that had the weird "14301" numbers in the name - this is typically seen with USB-to-RS-232 chipset driver. The "14301" is actually the serial number of that chip. This can be a handy way to consistently identity a specific USB serial device - no matter the order, they are plugged in.

If you have a more involved setup, I would recommend a program named `serial-monitor` available [here](https://crates.io/crates/serial-monitor). It allows you to list all the available serial ports with lots of information, and allows you to filter that list by criterion such as serial number, manufacturer, product or even port number. You can then get from "device made by company XYZ" to "/dev/cu.usbserial-9812938". It is very handy when scripting.